# HG - why does it cause my system to become unresponsive

Tags: mercurial

I am using HG, mercurial, to backup some binary and text files (about 12G worth).  I am pushing to a remote repository and my system becomes unresponsive (the mouse and keyboard don't do anything).

The CPU is busy, but not flat-lined, also, I have about 1.5GB of free memory.

What is causing my system to choke?  This is the first time I have ever pushed the contents to the repository, so there should be about 3.5GB of total data to transmit (how much space HG is using).

Comment: Is it a lot of small files making up the 12GB, or a few large files? Hashes are built on the first commit (which remote verifies), so ...

Comment: Pretty sure the problem is the memory, dead keyboard and mouse are good indicators that the system is swapping. You could try pushing only some revisions, see it it helps (hg push -r 0 ; hg push -r 1; etc.). If it does it might indicate a memory leak somewhere in hg.

Comment: Ok, I use git on another machine that pushes much more than that and I don't have any issues.  When I do this with hg, I have to eventually kill my machine as it becomes unusable.  I haven't tried SSHing into the box to kill / observe what is going on, but I will try that if I get a chance.

Comment: Can you watch your memory usage over time on the client and the server?

Comment: I was, it was steady at about 2.1 GB (I have 4GB), the system unexpectedly became slow and unresponsive.  There was no warning.  I also should indicate that I am not running swap.

Answer (score 1):

Try running Process Monitor to get a log of what HG is trying to do while your computer is hung.